# How to get what word is after another word using discord.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, discord, discord.js

I am trying to build something similar to Dad bot, but I can figure out how to do the "Hi __ I'm, Dad"

This is the code that I have so far:

```
var imWords = ["i'm", "I'm", "i'M", "I'M", "im", "Im", "iM", "IM"]


bot.on ('message', msg => {
    for (var i = 0; i < imWords.length; i++) {
        if (msg.content.includes(imWords[i])) {
            msg.channel.send('Hi, I am Dad')
        break;
        };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the index, then slice, and combine with [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
const imWords = ["i'm", "I'm", "i'M", "I'M", "im", "Im", "iM", "IM"];

bot.on('message', msg => {
    for (var i = 0; i < imWords.length; i++) {
        const index = msg.content.indexOf(imWords[i]);
        if (index !== -1) {
            // add one to include the space
            const name = msg.content.slice(index + imWords[i].length + 1);
            msg.channel.send(`Hi, ${name}, I am Dad`);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```js
 bot.on ('message', msg => {
  var imWords = ["i'm","im"]
    for (var i = 0; i < imWords.length; i++) {
        const text = msg.content.toLowerCase();  
          if (text.includes(imWords[i])) {
             msg.channel.send('Hi {msg.author}, I am Dad');
    break;
 }});
```